# How detect in flexbox item is wrapped?

Tags: css, flexbox

How can I detect in my [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YpGLGa) last `<div>` is wrapped to next row? I want set in this `<div>` `margin-left: 0`. It is only example.

Answer (score 1):

How about only applying margins to bottom and right of each box.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #e9e9e9;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
.container div {
  background: #a3a3a3;
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```